# Can't call nodeify on async function but can call then()

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have these 2 functions.

```
async function testAsync(){
    console.log('async func')
}

function callback(){
    console.log('callback function.')
}
```

When I call `then` on `async` it works, similar to the `promise`. For example, the following code works.

```
bluebird.resolve().then(()=> console.log('then promise'))
testAsync().then(()=> console.log('then async'))
```

But when I call `nodeify` on `async` then it gives error. Although, it works for `promise`

Works ->`bluebird.resolve().nodeify(callback)`

Error -> `testAsync().nodeify(callback)`

This is the error that I got. Why so?

```
TypeError: testAsync(...).nodeify is not a function
```

Comment: In short, `.nodify()` is a sugar method of Bluebird promises. Native javascript promises have no such method.

Comment: Use `Bluebird.resolve(testAsync()).nodify(callback)`

Comment: Should use `.asCallback()` instead of `.nodeify()` with the newer Bluebird.  Previous comment misspelled `nodeify`

Answer (score 0):

The error states that there is no `nodeify` function on the native promise object.

If you need to use this function, which you really shouldn't, you have to get it from the promise implementation that defines it and call it on the object something like `p.prototype.nodeify.call(testAsync())` and then hope that it does not use any internal parts of the promise implementation.

Or better extract the function from the promise implementation because it is only something like this:

```
function nodeify(cb) {
  this.then(function (v) { cb(null, v) });
  this.catch(function (err) { cb(err) });
}
```

which can be used as `nodeify.call(testAsync(), callback)`